# What is the most efficient way to store and search for tagged data where tags have weights?

Tags: sql, sql-server, tags, full-text-search

I need to keep thousands of rows in a database (SQL Server). Each row needs to have tags. Now, when I search for rows, I pass tags specified by the user and I need to return only those rows where at least one tag is present. Another requirement is that each tag has its own weight so the result set must be sorted by the calculated ranking.

For example, when I have two rows, one has tag A and the second has tag B, and tag A has a predefined weight 0.9 and B weights 0.5, then the row with tag A appears higher in the list.

Now, to solve this problem, I have created a table where I have a separate nvarchar column where I keep my tags, separated by a comma. I created a full-text search catalog for this column. When I search for rows I use `CONTAINSTABLE` along with `ISABOUT` as, after getting familiar with all full-text search features offered by SQL Server, this one seemed to work best for this scenario.

```
SELECT Items.*  
FROM Items   
INNER JOIN CONTAINSTABLE(Items, Tags,   
    'ISABOUT (
        “tag1” WEIGHT (.8),   
        “tag2” WEIGHT (.4), 
        “tag3” WEIGHT (.2) )', LANGUAGE 0) AS KEY_Items
    ON Items.Id = KEY_Items.[KEY]  
ORDER BY KEY_Items.RANK DESC;
```

It works great but I am wondering if this is the most efficient way of doing that and whether there are no gotchas in this solution that can bite me in the future?

Comment: Normally, this would be done with a separate `ItemTags` table with one row per item and tag.  I am not sure how  the performance of the full text search would compare to that solution.

Comment: Yeah, this was my initial design but unfortunately `CONTAINSTABLE` has limitations to my knowledge and cannot do ranked and weighed searches that span multiple tables... Unless there is some nice trick and providing that it does not impact performance.